# Scrolling a tk.Text with the yview_scroll method results in a glitch sometimes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `tk.Text` widget inside a frame, that is inside a `Notebook`. Inside the tk.Text I embed another tk.Frame that has a tk.Frame header and a tk.Text content. The problem is that when I try to scroll the main tk.Text, from bottom to top, a pure black background box appears as I scroll up, eventually disappears after more scrolling. Doesn't happen when scrolling down. This only happens when `self.yview_scroll(-2, "units")` is used. If I scroll by it's normal events with the mousewheel or scrollbar it doesn't happen. But I need to scroll programmatically sometimes. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

[image]

In this image the embeded frame is below, the header being `Language: rust`. This happens when I scroll up from the bottom.
Also this only happens at certain window sizes like for example `--width 900 --height 1000`.

This is how I add the embeded (Snippet) frame:

````py
def format_snippets(self) -> None:
    from .snippet import Snippet
    start_index = self.position
    text = self.get(start_index, "end-1c")
    pattern = r"^```([\w#]*)\n(.*?)\n```$"
    matches = []

    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
        language = match.group(1)
        content_start = match.start(2)
        content_end = match.end(2)
        matches.append((content_start, content_end, language))

    for content_start, content_end, language in reversed(matches):
        start_line_col = self.index_at_char(content_start, start_index)
        end_line_col = self.index_at_char(content_end, start_index)
        snippet_text = self.get(start_line_col, end_line_col)
        self.delete(f"{start_line_col} - 1 lines linestart", f"{end_line_col} + 1 lines lineend")

        snippet = Snippet(self, snippet_text, language)
        self.window_create(f"{start_line_col} - 1 lines", window=snippet)
        self.snippets.append(snippet)
````

For now I'm using this as a workaround:

```py
def get_fraction(self, num_lines: int = 1) -> float:
    total_lines = self.count("1.0", "end-1c lineend", "displaylines")[0]
    fraction = num_lines / total_lines
    return fraction

def scroll_up(self, check: bool = False) -> None:
    fraction = self.get_fraction()
    self.yview_moveto(self.yview()[0] - fraction)
```

It calculates the % of a single line.

Comment: Have you tried using `ScrolledText` widget ? Also,  you can use `widget.see(index)` to programmatically scroll to specific lines (this is a method of `Text` class). Use `END` constant for the last line.

Comment: Isn't ScrolledText just a prepared Text with Scrollbar or does it provide more functionality? Also thanks I'll consider using See().

Comment: Not sure if See() would work when there are embeded widgets, how would you tell it to go 1 line above/below always?

Comment: The `ScrolledText` indeed is a `Text` and `Scrollbar` packed together and it inherits all functionalities from the `Text` widget as well. I used it one of my projects were I wanted to scroll programmatically to the last entered line, every time a new line is entered. So after every `insert` command, i call `see(END)` so that the widget scrolls to the last line.